Restrict method on generic class based on generic type parameter in TypeScript
In given function, last function should give a compilation error as it is not allowed.
interface IQuery<T> {
    first<U = T & object>(): Promise<U>
    sum(): Promise<T>;
    map<TR>(fx: (x: T) => TR): IQuery<TR>;
}

async function fx(q: IQuery<Product>) {
    // type is correct
    const total = await q.map((x) => x.price).sum();

    // type is correct
    const firstProduct = await q.map((x) => x).first();

    // type is never, this doesn't give compilation error
    const firstID = await q.map((x) => x.id).first();

}

class Product {
    id?: number;
    price?: number;
}


Last line in function fx compiles successfully however the return type is never but it doesn't give me compilation error.
Basically, method first cannot be called unless map returns an object, not a literal.
How should I restrict first<U = T & object>(): Promise<U>?
I have tried

first<U = T extends object ? T : never>(): Promise<U>
first<U = T>(): U extends object ? Promise<U> : never;

Here is playground link,
TypeScript Playground Code
Updated code by Alexander works but doesn't allow inheriting from IQuery again to add few more methods.
TypeScript Playground Code

Basically you should make first() not valid if T doesn't extend object, the error message is though kind of cryptic:
Playground
interface IQuery<T> {
    first(this: T extends object ? IQuery<T> : never): Promise<T>
    sum(): Promise<T>;
    map<TR>(fx: (x: T) => TR): IQuery<TR>;
}

async function fx(q: IQuery<Product>) {
    // type is correct
    const total = await q.map((x) => x.price).sum();

    // type is correct
    const firstProduct = await q.map((x) => x).first();

    // The 'this' context of type 'IQuery<number | undefined>' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'never'.(2684)
    const firstID = await q.map((x) => x.id).first();


}

class Product {
    id?: number;
    price?: number;
}

With a type it looks better:
Playground
type IQuery<T> = {
    sum(): Promise<T>;
    map<TR>(fx: (x: T) => TR): IQuery<TR>;
} & (T extends object ? {first(): Promise<T>} : {})


async function fx(q: IQuery<Product>) {
    // type is correct
    const total = await q.map((x) => x.price).sum();

    // type is correct
    const firstProduct = await q.map((x) => x).first();

    // Property 'first' does not exist on type '{ sum(): Promise<number | undefined>; map<TR>(fx: (x: number | undefined) => TR): IQuery<TR>; }'
    const firstID = await q.map((x) => x.id).first();


}

class Product {
    id?: number;
    price?: number;
}


This is interesting, but there is an issue with this code as I cannot inherit the other interface from IQuery, I have IOrderedQuery which has methods orderBy and thenBy. Ref https://github.com/Entity-Access/entity-access/blob/main/src/model/IFilterWithParameter.ts

@AkashKava in the first case i was able to extends from IQuery interface, could you make a playground snippet to show the problem?

I have updated the question with 2nd link that doesn't work for inheriting from IQuery

@AkashKava yes, of course you can't extends an interface from a type. you rather use the first case with interfaces or the second with types only

Hey, Sorry I didn't see your first case, I scrolled down and only tried the 2nd one, I think this is doable. Thanks.
